# Table join or virtual layer to match multiple points to geometry

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, spatial-query

I have:

- a non-spatial table of multiple test results with reference to non-unique locations, and
- a spatial layer that has all the locations (multiple results per location)

I can do table joins between the locations layer to the results, but I get stuck because each location has multiple results...

I suspect I need to make a virtual layer assigning the geometry to each result, but I get lost at the "query" stage. The QGIS manual goes deep into database SQL queries but I am hoping there is a simpler solution for the non-initiated?

Note: I can create virtual "x" and "y" attribute columns and join them to my table, but still missing a step to use the coordinates in creating the virtual layer

Comment: Please add a sample of your tests / locations and the desired output.

Comment: Sorry @JGH - I should have. I am still struggling a bit with the formatting of questions, inserting tables and images, etc. The example Luis provided below is perfect thought, and his answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual layer is your answer :

for example two tables,

```
nonspatial table:
id|Restaurant|costumer
1 | Rest1    | george
2 | Rest1    | Peter
3 | Rest2    | grace
4 | Rest2    | Peter


spatial table:
id | Restaurant | geometry
1  | Rest1      | Point(1,0)
2  | Rest2      | Point(1,2)
3  | Rest3      | Point(2,0)
```

your query

```
select "nonspatial".*, "spatial"."geometry" 
from "nonspatial", "spatial"
where "nonspatial"."Restaurant"="spatial"."Restaurant"
```

Result

```
id|Restaurant|costumer|geometry
1 | Rest1    | george |Point(1,0)
2 | Rest1    | Peter  |Point(1,0)
3 | Rest2    | grace  |Point(1,2)
4 | Rest2    | Peter  |Point(1,2)
```

tip - if your tables and columns are in lowercase, quotes are not necessary

Comment: This is awesome Luis, thank you so much. The query is extremely easy to read and I replicated with the actual data on first try. I did not realise accessing the geometry of the spatial table was that easy! I really need to learn more about spatial query - is there a gentle introduction / manual that I could start with?

Comment: you are welcome.. my sql knowledge came from postgis and postgres but for start i think spatialite  is very powerful.   [gaia-gis link]( https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-tutorial-2.3.1.html)