# Fields with both numbers and letters don't join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a bizarre problem with QGIS. I'm trying to join a .csv file with a shapefile, and the join field is a precinct code. Some precinct codes in my .csv are purely numbers, but some have a letter attached at the end.[image]

The join field in question is the third column (example: 321001A). As you can see, the precinct codes with a letter at the end did not transfer correctly. What should I do?

Comment: Try to use "virtual Layer" instead, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/338896/87346 for how to proceed

Comment: OK, importing it as a string AND capitalizing all the letters did the trick. God this is finicky stuff.

Comment: If you have the solution, could you please answer the question and accept the answer. It will help others whi may have similar issues and remove this question from the unanswered pile

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? I have noticed earlier that it reads some of the first lines to decide which type each field is. If a table starts up with enough numbers in what is really , QGIS will then read the field as a number and get into problems when there are nun numeric characters. Trying to test this with the last version (3.26.1) QGIS is at least reading the first 50 lines to find the type of field before importing. If you know there are non-numerics in a field that is set to numeric, it can be changed manually.