# Create virtual line layer based on points and connectivity list?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, spatial-query, virtual-layer

I have two layers:

- *myPoints*: a spatial point layer with an attribute field "ID" (entries are unique).
- *connectivityList*: a non-spatial attribute table with two fields (idFrom, idTo). Here, the entries are not unique (i.e, a single point from *myPoints* can appear multiple times in the list, both as start and end point).

My goal is to draw one line for each row in the connectivity list that goes from one point (with `ID == idFrom`) to another point (with `ID == idTo`). How can I achieve this?

I would love a solution that just links the layers instead of baking them together, as the point coordinates will change in the future and I would like the lines to automatically adapt. I guess I am looking for a virtual layer, but I could not figure out how to set it up. [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338845/table-join-or-virtual-layer-to-match-multiple-points-to-geometry) seems very related, but I don't know how to select both of my points and connect them by a line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

General query to relate your layers in a *Virtual Layer*:

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  MakeLine(f.geometry, t.geometry) AS geometry
FROM
  "connectivityList" AS c
  JOIN
  "myPoints" AS f
    ON c."idFrom" = f."ID"
  JOIN
  "myPoints" AS t
    ON c."idTo" = t."ID"
;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! All lines are displayed and even the Identification tool works.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use an expression using geometry generator.

1. Make an new style layer for the point layer.
2. Choose "Geometry Generator", "LineString/MultiLineString" for "Symbol layer type" and "Geometry type" respectively.
3. Paste the following expression.

   ```
   make_line(
     $geometry,
     geometry(
       get_feature(
         @layer,
         'ID',
         attribute(
           get_feature(
             'connectivityList',
             'idFrom',
             ID
           ),
           'idTo'))))
   ```

[image]

Then the lines automatically adapt.

[image]

Comment: It works partly, but thank you very much already. Using the geometry generator is a good idea. The remaining problem is: if one point occurs multiple times as a "fromID" in the connectivity list, only the first row in the list will be drawn. I have edited the question to make it clear.